# NSURLSessionDownloadTask concurrent downloads, also supported in app background, not working as expected

Tags: cocoa-touch, concurrency, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

**Requirement:**

I have a view controller class, in which I am showing a collection view. In it for each cell I am checking if image already exists in local or not, if it does not exist then I am trying to download the image from server and showing the same.

**Implementation:**

Below is the code for the same:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // retrieving associated product
    Products *aProduct = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UICollectionViewCell* newCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kProductIconIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // setup of image view and cell label
    UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[collectionView viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];
    cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[newCell viewWithTag:klabelTag];

    // assigning value to cell label and image view
    NSString *productImageLocalPath = aProduct.imageLocalPath;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:productImageLocalPath]) {
        // file exists at local path :-)
        // means less fun :-(
        cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:productImageLocalPath];
    }
    else
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *downloadActivityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[newCell viewWithTag:kActivityIndicator];
        downloadActivityIndicator.hidden = NO;
        [downloadActivityIndicator startAnimating];

        // file does not exist at local path :-(
        // means more fun :-)
        [self.sessionController setupAndStartDownloadTaskForProduct:aProduct withCompletionHandler:^(NSString * tempLocalPath){
            // download was successful

            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tempLocalPath];
            [imageData writeToFile:productImageLocalPath atomically:YES];

            cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [downloadActivityIndicator stopAnimating];

        } andFailureHandler:^{
            cellImageView.image = nil;
            [downloadActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }];
    }

    // setting values
    cellLabel.text = aProduct.imageName;

    return newCell;
}
```

In session controller class, I have below method to start a new download task:

```
- (void)setupAndStartDownloadTaskForProduct:(Products *)aProduct withCompletionHandler:(DownloadedCompletionHandler)completionHandler andFailureHandler:(DownloadedFailureHandler)failureHandler
{
    NSString *completeImagePath = [kBasePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aProduct.imageRelativePath];

    NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:completeImagePath];

    if (!self.session) {
        [self setUpSession];
    }

    NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:downloadRequest];

    NSDictionary *downloadInfoDict = @{kSuccessHandlerKey: [completionHandler copy], kFailureHandlerKey: [failureHandler copy]};

    self.downloadTasks[@(downloadTask.taskIdentifier)] = downloadInfoDict;

    // resuming the download task
    [downloadTask resume];

}
```

In above method I am storing successHandler and failureHandler block in a dictionary, mapping it with download task using its task identifier.

Below is the implementation of didFinishDownloadingToURL method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // invoking success block
        DownloadedCompletionHandler successCompletionHandler = self.downloadTasks[@(downloadTask.taskIdentifier)][kSuccessHandlerKey];
        successCompletionHandler([location path]);

        // removing download task key-value pair from dictionary
        [self.downloadTasks removeObjectForKey:@(downloadTask.taskIdentifier)];
    });
}
```

**My problem is -** sometimes in above method downloadTask returns a different identifier than the one initiated at setupAndStartDownloadTaskForProduct, because of which successCompletionHandler is obtained as nil, and app crashes when I try to invoke the handler block.

Now my questions are:

1. Why in didFinishDownloadingToURL I am getting a different identifier, than the one initiated at  setupAndStartDownloadTaskForProduct?
2. If this is the expected behavior then what is the best way to implement my requirement?

Comment: Can you please post your code for `self.session`?

Answer (score 0):

The taskIdentifier that you are using is obviously an NSUInteger.  What you are doing is using an NSNumber as a key with the literal shortcut:

`NSNumber * key = @(downloadTask.taskIdentifier);`

The problem is that using anything other than an NSString for a key in a dictionary is a bad idea. What you have done is create an NSNumber object that has the same value but does not guarantee that the -isEqual: evaluates to be true.

Instead of using NSNumber keys, convert the key to a string:

`NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", downloadTask.taskIdentifier];`

Then the dictionary hash will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out [this post](http://lazyloadinginuiscrollviewiniphone.blogspot.in/2011/12/lazy-loading-in-uitableview-in-iphone.html) of lazy loading images into a UITableView?

Maybe you can customize it for UICollectionView.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That link is a serious step back from what the poster was using.